# Interior of a set than sounds easy

Tags: calculus

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ an open set (it can be cosidered bounded if needed), and
$\phi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function with $\phi^{-1}(0)\neq\emptyset$ and $\nabla\phi(x)\neq 0,\ \forall\ x\in\phi^{-1}(0)$. Is it true that:

$$\mathrm{int}\overline{\phi^{-1}([0,\infty))}=\phi^{-1}((0,\infty))$$
?

Remark that one inclusion is obvious. I cannot find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is given by the function
$$\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto (x - 1)^2 - 1$$